# Where are Android logcat files stored?

Tags: android, logcat

I'm looking for the log file(s) that are made by logcat.  Where are they typically stored?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They are stored as circular memory buffers on the device.  If you run "adb logcat > myfile" on your host system, you can retrieve the content into a file.

Comment: but how can I specify the program that I want to debug

Comment: you'll have to filter out entries that you don't want - for instance, with `grep -v`.

Comment: what if I have a device with buggy drivers (Moverio BT-200) and I can't do USB debugging via adb? Can I retrieve them in some other way?

Comment: If everything is a file, where is that circular memory buffer file stored then?

Comment: @mchud "everything is a file" is wrong. It's in a **memory** area so this means if the device is powered off, it's immediately lost.

Answer (score 33):

To get post-mortem information from a device it is helpful to see the timestamp as well. To let you know when the event occurred, try:
**adb logcat -d -v time > logfile.txt**

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to see the current contents of the log, you can do 
adb logcat -d > myfile

It will exit after dumping the log.

(suravi's suggestion would be good if you wanted to watch the log while testing.)

Comment: This answer... Thank you!