# Xamarin App not working in release mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-ndk

I need some help figuring out what the problem is.
I have a brand new installation of VS2017 fully updated

When I run my app in debug mode it works, when I run the app in release mode it would just hung at the splash screen, I tried to check the device log but I can only see IlligalStateException

I changed the Java Heap to 1G, but it did not solve the problem
I am upgraded to Xamarin.Forms 3.0 and I am compiling using Android 8.1, that did not solve the problem (also tried to lower the version)

I set the Linking to None, that only increased the app size and did not solve the problem
When I uncheck the "Bundle assemblies into native code" it then works but I have always been compiling my apps with this. (and it works in debug mode)

I checked the version of the NDK it is currently set to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r15c" Not sure if the version is incorrect that I am using since this is also a new laptop (my other laptop was stolen where everything compiled and worked perfectly)
It also seem that the Device Log is lagging and doesn't want to filter. Device Monitor seems to be crashing aswell.

I just tried to upgrade to nds-16 but that didn't work aswell.
For now I am compiling without it but I would like to compile with it again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin App runs on debug but crashes on release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49649627/xamarin-app-runs-on-debug-but-crashes-on-release)

Answer (score 0):

Try first uninstall your app:

```
adb uninstall <your.package.name>
```

Maybe you use a different keystore for the signing.

You can set the log verbosity to diagnostic in order that you see the problem:

```
Tools/Options/Xamarin/Xamarin Diagnostic Output verbosity
Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run/ output verbosity
```